# Dúvida: Qual a melhor forma de exibir dados numa tabela?

Tags: jquery, json, jsp

estou estudando JSP e Servlets e também JQuery e me deparei com uma situação.

**Situação:**

Imagine que você vai exibir uma tabela de produtos onde serão exibidos 20 itens por página por exemplo. Com isso, você tem aquele famoso operador (que eu não lembro o nome):

> **Página anterior - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - Próxima página**

Como “operar” esse “operador”???

**Caso 1:**

- Tudo isso é controlado pelo *Server Side*, ou seja, o clique em cada
  botão manipula uma consulta ao SGBD ou há uma lista criada;
  (Independentemente de linguagem de programação).

**Caso 2:**

- Pode ser controlado pelo no *Client Side*, através de um JSON gerado
  pelo servidor e manipulado pelo JQuery.

Pensando de uma forma geral, num e-commerce, página pública ou um sistema web privativo.
Sendo um dos casos acima ou até mesmo um outro caso, existe uma forma correta ou mais fácil de fazer isso?

Eu procurei tópicos que me sanassem essa dúvida mas não encontrei, por isso abri esse!